How to set a custom icon in Android's ActionBar using Kotlin?
I'm trying to replace the default back button icon in my Android Activity's ActionBar with a custom icon. I'm using Kotlin and have tried the following code in my Activity:
supportActionBar?.apply {
    setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    setIcon(R.drawable.ic_custom_back) // Replace with your custom icon
}
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    finish()
    return true
}

However, the custom icon (ic_custom_back) is not appearing. The default back button icon is still displayed.

I've ensured that the custom drawable is correctly placed in the res/drawable folder and has the appropriate dimensions.

Can you please try this answer.
